# While LOOP to stop

Tags: oracle, plsql, while-loop

I  am trying to figure out how to write this into a WHILE LOOP and stop when it reaches 24.
This what I have so far when I run it it just keeps going forever.

```
DECLARE
    startD DATE := SYSDATE;
    monthlyP NUMBER(8,2) := 120;
    totalP NUMBER(3) :=24;
    dueD DATE;

BEGIN
    WHILE totalP <=24 LOOP
        totalP := totalP -1;
        startD := add_months(startD,1);
    
        dbms_output.put_line('Payment Number' || totalP);
        dbms_output.put_line('Date Due' || startD);
        dbms_output.put_line('Payment amount $'||to_char(monthlyP,'$9999.99'));
        dbms_output.put_line('Donation balance' || totalP );

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: You run `totalP := totalP -1`, i.e. it goes 24,23,22,21,20... And your loop condition says `WHILE totalP <=24` - which is always true! Maybe `WHILE totalP > 0 LOOP`

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce a "counter" variable, set it to 0, and increase this by 1 at every iteration eg

```
DECLARE
startD DATE := SYSDATE;
monthlyP NUMBER(8,2) := 120;
totalP constant NUMBER(3) := 24;
counter number := 0 ;
dueD DATE;


BEGIN
  WHILE counter < totalP LOOP
    counter := counter + 1;

    startD := add_months(startD,1);
    -- use to_char() - explicit conversion - for every || here ...
    dbms_output.put_line('Payment Number ' || to_char( counter ) );
    dbms_output.put_line('Date Due ' || to_char( startD, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) );
    dbms_output.put_line('Payment amount $ '||to_char(monthlyP,'$9999.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line('Donation balance ' || to_char( totalP ) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

When you have a fixed number of iterations, you can also use a FOR loop, which would make the code more compact (not by much, but still ...)

```
DECLARE
  startD DATE := SYSDATE;
  monthlyP NUMBER(8,2) := 120;
  totalP constant NUMBER(3) := 24;
  dueD DATE;
BEGIN
  for counter in 1 .. totalP
  loop
    startD := add_months(startD,1);
  
    dbms_output.put_line('Payment Number ' || to_char( counter ) );
    dbms_output.put_line('Date Due ' || to_char( startD, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) );
    dbms_output.put_line('Payment amount $ '||to_char(monthlyP,'$9999.99'));
    dbms_output.put_line('Donation balance ' || to_char( totalP - counter ) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[DBfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46ec0327904195ca65590397782a3398)